# When something is morally permitted and has more utility for you, should it come down to virtue whether or not you do it?

Tags: virtue-ethics

When something is morally permitted and has more utility for you, should it come down to virtue whether or not you do it? I'm thinking yes, and obviously so, but it's weird that it would be *obvious*. Take as an example safely becoming an escort to escape a life of extreme poverty etc,. Supposing it is not otherwise an immoral career, should the decision be about virtue, even given the personal utility will surely outweigh the oddity of turning tricks?

Comment: Your question alludes to both utilitarianism and virtue ethics. What are you refering to when you say something is "morally permitted" ?

Comment: yeah @armand i guess i am asking whether virtue ethics takes the slack for decisions that are not moral ones. do i need to define meta-ethics for morality for the question to be answered? idt so.

Comment: you can [see](https://www.askphilosophers.org/question/26532) that i might mean utilitarian morality or not @armand

Comment: Please don't get mad because i dared asking for clarification. But yes obviously the clearer you are in what you are asking the better answers you will get. If you feel like the link in your comment might help make your intent clearer, feel free to include it in your question. Again, sorry for trying to help you formulate your question, it won't happen again.

Comment: i'm not mad with you i'm mentally ill @armand please don't respond to my clarifications with passive aggression